# Making commonly used elements in template editable

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, include, themes

So I'm developing a Wordpress theme for a client, and I'd like to give them the power to edit a number of things that appear in the template code. Things like the single line of text in the footer, or the phone number in the header.

I've been searching for a plugin that allows me to have a part of the admin for "common elements" or something like that, where they can edit simple text fields, and I can stick a bit of PHP code in the templates, so that when they update their phone number, it will update the number in all places within their template.

Sort of like an editable "include" in a sense.

So I'm keen to know if anybody has knowledge of a plugin that would do this easily - or if anybody knows how to write something small (I'm presuming in the functions.php file) that could make this possible.

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not add a theme options page?

that will give the user the ability to add/change the telephone number along with footer text etc..

add this to your themes function.php file..

```
require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-options.php' );
```

create the new file called "theme-options.php" this will reside in the theme folder..

copy & paste the code below...

In the top of your header.php file or where you want to show the telephone number simply make a call to grab the theme options,

```
$themeOptions = get_option( 'my_theme_options' );
```

from here you can use the `<?php echo $themeOptions['sitetel'];?>` to print out the saved telephone number.... also in your footer,

you can put `<?php echo $themeOptions['copyright'];?>`

As an added bonus :) I've included a simple shortcode you can use in posts & pages for calling the theme telephone number...

when in a post or page, just put the shortcode [tel] to print out the number in posts..
if, and when the telephone number needs to change simply change it in the theme options page and it will be changed site wide..

good luck...

Marty

```
<?php
// CUSTOM THEME OPTIONS PAGE
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_theme_options_init' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_theme_options_add_page' );

/**
 * Init plugin options to white list our options
*/
function my_theme_options_init()
{
    register_setting( 'my_theme_options', 
                      'my_theme_options', 
                      'my_theme_options_validate' );
}

/**
 * Load up the menu page
 */
function my_theme_options_add_page() 
{
    add_theme_page( __( 'Theme Options', 
                        'my_theme' ), 
                         __( 'Theme Options', 
                        'my_theme' ), 
                        'edit_theme_options', 
                        'my_theme_options', 
                        'my_theme_options_do_page' 
                      );
}

/**
 * Create the options page
 */
function my_theme_options_do_page() 
{
    global $select_options, $radio_options;

    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) )
        $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] = false;

    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <?php echo "<h2>" . get_current_theme() . __( ' Theme Options', 'my_theme' ) . "</h2>"; ?>

        <?php 
        if ( false !== $_REQUEST['settings-updated'] ) : 
        ?>
            <div class="updated fade">
                <p>
                           <strong>
                                <?php _e( 'Theme Options saved', 'my_theme' ); ?>
                           </strong>
                        </p>
            </div>
        <?php 
        endif; 
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php 
        settings_fields( 'my_theme_options' ); 
        $options = get_option( 'my_theme_options' ); 
        ?>
                  <table class="form-table">
              <?php //SITE TELEPHONE NUMBER ?>
            <tr valign="top">
                       <th scope="row">
                         <?php _e( 'Telephone Number', 'my_theme' ); ?>
                       </th>
                        <td>
                           <input id="my_theme_options[sitetel]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="my_theme_options[sitetel]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['sitetel'] ); ?>" />
                        <label class="description" for="my_theme_options[sitetel]"><?php _e( 'Website Telephone Number', 'my_theme' ); ?></label>
                        <br />
                        <small>Use the shortcode <strong>[tel]</strong> to display telephone number in posts</small> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php // COPYRIGHT ?>
                <tr valign="top"><th scope="row"><?php _e( 'Copyright', 'my_theme' ); ?></th>
                    <td>
                        <input id="my_theme_options[copyright]" class="regular-text" type="text" name="my_theme_options[copyright]" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $options['copyright'] ); ?>" />
                        <label class="description" for="rehab_theme_options[copyright]"><?php _e( 'footer Copyright text', 'my_theme' ); ?></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>

            <p class="submit">
                <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e( 'Save Options', 'my_theme' ); ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php 
}



/**
 * Sanitize and validate input. Accepts an array, return a sanitized array.
 */
function my_theme_options_validate( $input ) {

    global $select_options, $radio_options;

    // Say our text option must be safe text with no HTML tags
    $input['sitetel']   = wp_filter_post_kses( $input['sitetel'] );
    $input['copyright']     = wp_filter_post_kses( $input['copyright'] );

    return $input;
}




// SHOW THEME OPTION TELEPHONE NUMBER
function my_theme_show_tel_number()
{
    $options = get_option( 'my_theme_options' );
    return "<strong style='color:#036;'>".$options['sitetel']."</strong>";
}

// ADD TEL SHORTCODE
function my_theme_register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('tel', 'my_theme_show_tel_number');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_register_shortcodes');
?>
```

Comment: OK, this is exactly what I was looking for! I had thought about using a "content blocks" plugin - but it seemed overkill, but this solution is likely to be ideal. Thank you!

Comment: Cool... just play about the theme-options.php file, change it to suit your needs and theme,, should all work out in the end,, also, you can add your own logo / html etc inside the div wrap... to show on the theme options page..